# Как грамотно описать логику обращения к базе данных (архитектуру классов)?

Tags: android, sqlite

Пример: есть приложение, в нем три активности и все три активности работают с базой данных (чтение/запись).
условие: работа с базой данных ведется в отдельной нити.

Как логичнее и грамотнее написать код для этого?

Сначала я хотел выделить всю логику работы в отдельный класс (который наследуется от Async Task), в него передаются данные на основе которых он формирует запросы и возвращает ссылку на данные. 
Или же лучше сделать в каждой активности отдельные классы Async Task которые будут отдельно работать друг от друга. 
Или есть варианты? Как это обычно реализуется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обращения к БД сейчас лучше использовать свой загрузчик на основе CursorLoader. CursorLoader расширяет класс AsyncTaskLoader и загружает данные в бэкграундном процессе не блокируя пользовательский интерфейс.